# Tabs with view pager within a fragment - android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have a static menu on the left side of my screen in my android application.Whenever I click an item from the left menu a `fragment` will appear along side it.

One of my items on the left menu is the course. In the course `fragment` contains a `viewpager` to watch read or listen to the course. You can navigate to one of these three options by side swipe or clicking the corresponding tab on the title bar. This all works fine.

However if I click another item on the left menu bar and navigate back to the course section, it messes up. The `onCreateView()` is invoked again and therefore adds the tabs to the title bar again and the `viewpager`. I tried removing all tabs in the `onPause()` method and removing all views in the `viewpager`. The tabs no longer be added again, but the pages on the screen are now blank.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the class which `extends FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new WatchCourseFrag();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new ReadCourseFrag();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new ListenCourseFrag();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

and here is the tab `fragment` class:

```
public class TabFrag2 extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Watch", "Read", "Listen" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = ((HomeScreenTablet) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        viewPager.removeAllViews();
        viewPager.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
Changed "TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter" to "TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter"